# My code is ignoring small floats when adding and dividng

Tags: c++, floating-point, addition, average, division

for class we were given a code that essentially takes the numbers 10000000000, 3, -10000000000, and 5, prints them, adds them together, and then divides them by four to make the average. They're all marked as floats, and when the code spits out the average, it ignores the 3 and 5 in the equation. I found that replacing the "const float" with "double" fixes it, but the assignment is to find a way to do it without changing the identifier types. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>



using namespace std;



int main(void)

{

   const float YEAR_ONE = 10000000000;

   const float YEAR_TWO = 3;

   const float YEAR_THREE = -10000000000;

   const float YEAR_FOUR = 5;

   int numberOfYears = 4;



   float average = YEAR_ONE + YEAR_TWO;

   average += YEAR_THREE + YEAR_FOUR;

   average = average/numberOfYears;

   cout << fixed;
   cout << setprecision(2);

   cout << "1998 earnings were: $" << YEAR_ONE << endl;

   //Prints the amount earned in 1998

   cout << "1999 earings were: $" <<  YEAR_TWO << endl;

   //Prints the amount earned in 1999

   cout << "2000 earnings were: $" << YEAR_THREE << endl;

   //Prints the amount earned in 2000

   cout << "2001 earnings were: $" << YEAR_FOUR << endl;

   //Prints the amount earned in 2001

   cout << "Average earnings was: $" << average << endl;

   //Prints the average amount earned between 1998 and 2001



return 0;

}
```

Comment: Well, floats don't have a lot of precision to begin with. And the precision actually drops the bigger the numbers get. So... no surprises really.

Comment: It sounds like the exercise is designed to teach you something. What have you learned so far? Can you relate it to something you have already talked about in class?

Comment: If you can't change the datatype, have a think about the order in which you add these values together.

Comment: Those numbers are too big for `float`. It will sacrifice precision to store them.

Comment: BTW "identifier" is the name you select for your variables, it is not the type. So if your assignment specifically states that you should not change the IDENTIFIERS, then by all means change all those variables to doubles and keep the existing names ;)

Comment: Even if the inputs and outputs are floats, consider using double for the intermediate values. Also consider [Kahan summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, everyone's beating around the bush.  So I'll give you a push in the right direction.

```
float average = YEAR_ONE + YEAR_TWO;
```

Think about that value above.  Does it fit in a float?  No - the value of `YEAR_TWO` is too small to be added to `YEAR_ONE`, so what you'll find is that `YEAR_ONE + YEAR_TWO == YEAR_ONE`.

The same goes for the other value (`YEAR_THREE + YEAR_FOUR`) that you add to `average`.

So how about you rearrange the order of the additions.  You can make those big nasty values go away.  This appears to be what the assignment is asking for, in an effort to help you understand some *gotchas* with floating-point precision.

I think you know what to do...

Answer (score 0):

That´s just how `float` works; it isn´t as precise as double.
To give a (simplified) idea ho numbers are stored:

```
2 => 2.00000 * 10^0
0.01 => 1.00000 * 10^(-2)
10000000000 => 1.00000 * 10^10
```

It can store about 5 decimal digits, and everything else is managed by the exponent.
A value like 10000000003 would be
`1.00000` 00003 `* 10^10`
with the white part cut out.

A more detailed explanation how the values are stored: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754